# Safe mode on LG Optimus 2X

Tags: reboot, tasker, lg-optimus-2x, safe-mode

I accidentally added a task to Tasker which reboots the phone on startup.
How do I boot into safe mode on LG Optimus 2X to disable it?

Comment: Have you tried holding the menu button while it boots up?  Do you have any reason to believe it *has* safe mode?

Answer (score 2):

If your G2x is rooted, the easiest work-around would be deleting the Tasker's data from recovery.  Download and install [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and LG's [drivers](http://www.lgforum.com/how_do_i_posts/installing-usb-drivers-for-the-optimus-vortex-and-ally-android-phones) for the G2x.  Reboot the G2x into recovery mode (preferably ClockworkMod), connect to PC, and in command prompt issue the following commands:

> cd C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\
>   adb shell
>   su
>   rm -rf /data/data/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm
>   reboot

This should remove all Tasker profiles, including the "bad" one.